# numpy.float64' object is not callable in auc(recall, precision)

Tags: python, object, machine-learning

The program throws `['numpy.float64' object is not callable]` error when I run :

```
auc(recall, precision)
```

I was able to run this successfully until today. I'd appreciate any help on this, thanks! I also tried it with () but it didn't work.

```
fit_logreg = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced', verbose=0)

fit_logreg.set_params(penalty = 'l2',
                  C = 0.00001, 
                  n_jobs=-1,
                  verbose=0
                  )
###########################################################
###4#TRAIN THE FITTING MODEL ON THE TRAINING DATASET###
###########################################################
# fit a model
fit_logreg.fit(trainX, trainy)

# score the test dataset

predictions_logreg = fit_logreg.predict(testX)
#predictions_logreg = predictions_logreg.values.ravel() 

###########################################################
###5#OOB ERROR AND CLASSIFICATION SUCCESS METRICS###
###########################################################

##ROC AUC SCORE
roc_auc_score(testy, predictions_logreg,average='macro')

##RECALL-PRECISION CURVE

# predict probabilities
probs = fit_logreg.predict_proba(testX)
# keep probabilities for the positive outcome only
probs = probs[:, 1]
# predict class values
yhat = predictions_logreg
# calculate precision-recall curve
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(testy, probs)
# calculate F1 score
f1 = f1_score(testy, yhat)

# calculate precision-recall AUC
auc(recall, precision)
```

This is the error I am getting :

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-74f87a22f33a> in <module>()
     68 # calculate precision-recall AUC
     69 #auc = auc(recall, precision)
---> 70 auc(recall, precision)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 15):

When you ran the following line (commented out in your traceback):

```
auc = auc(recall, precision)
```

you replaced the function `auc` in your namespace by a numpy object. Calling `auc` again threw the error.

Comment: got it, it there anything that I can do to avoid it?

Comment: You can generally just avoid any statement that will reassign an already used variable. That way, everything in your namespace has a single unchanging definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort this issue as below:

```
from sklearn import metrics

metrics.auc(recall, precision)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `print(auc(recall, precision))`